# Change index of multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've tried some solutions from:

[In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

[php array from multidimensional array keys values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716899/php-array-from-multidimensional-array-keys-values)

But its is not exacly what i need, i tried to mix some solutions but notting helped.

I have an array from my database:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [ID] => 1 
        [USER_ID] => 1
        [DATA] => UNIQUE 
        [VALUE] => buuu ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [ID] => 2 
        [USER_ID] => 1 
        [DATA] => NICKNAME 
        [VALUE] => NoAd ) )
```

And i want to transform that database to:

```
Array ( 
    [UNIQUE] => buuu
    [NICKNAME] => NoAd
    [any new [2]...[3]... from previous array
```

after that code:

```
foreach($playerdata as $segment){
                    foreach($segment as $key => $value ){
                    $newArray[$value] = $value;
                }
            }
```

my array looks like:

```
Array ( [UNIQUE] => UNIQUE 
        [buuu] => buuu 
        [NICKNAME] => NICKNAME 
        [NoAd] => NoAd )
```

i tried use 3x foreach but it ends in error all time i think i need to change some variables in my foreach but no idea how.

Comment: What? I can't see any logic here. Also you need to expand your example with more than "any new [2]...[3]... from previous array". And preferably a second item that needs to be merged so that we see a more complete picture

Comment: example 3:
[3] => Array (
        [ID] => any number 
        [USER_ID] => any number
        [DATA] => anything
        [VALUE] => something ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I see the other answers it seems it's [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) you are looking for.

It returns an array column and the third parameter is what the key name should be.

```
$player_data = array(array(
"ID" => 1,
"USER_ID" => 1,
"DATA" => "UNIQUE",
"VALUE" => "buuu"
),
array(
"ID" => 1,
"USER_ID" => 1,
"DATA" => "NICKNAME",
"VALUE" => "NoAd"
));
$new = array_column($player_data, "VALUE", "DATA");
var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["UNIQUE"]=>
  string(4) "buuu"
  ["NICKNAME"]=>
  string(4) "NoAd"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZAkgZ

There is no need for loops to solve this.

Comment: Thank You! that was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
$newArray = array();    
foreach($playerdata as $segment){
    $newArray[$segment['DATA']] = $segment['VALUE'];
}
```

This code gets the DATA as key and VALUE as value from each part of the array and stores it in `$newArray`.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume `$playerdata` has the below values

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [ID] => 1 
        [USER_ID] => 1
        [DATA] => UNIQUE 
        [VALUE] => buuu ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [ID] => 2 
        [USER_ID] => 1 
        [DATA] => NICKNAME 
        [VALUE] => NoAd ) ) 
    [2]----
    [3]----        

$newArray = [];
foreach($playerdata as $record) {
    $newArray[$record['DATA']] = $record['DATA'];
    $newArray[$record['VALUE']] = $record['VALUE'];
}

print_r($newArray);
```